# Java Timer schedule job at specific time - ignore dst adjustment

Tags: java, timer

We are using Java Timer (Java 1.7)  to schedule some print jobs.  We want the job to print at specific time every day regardless of DST.  Currently, if we set the job to print at 4:00 AM with period of 24hrs, it prints correctly until DST day.  On Fall DST day, it is printing at 3:00 AM instead of 4:00.  How can i fix this?  We want it to print at the specific time every day of the year.

Answer (score 1):

You would use `java.util.Calendar` to get the time (`Date`) since the `Calendar` class already does DST adjustments. See how the `DailyIterator.class` is implemented in [Listing 4. DailyIterator class](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-schedule/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

Implement your TimerTask as

```
class Task extends TimerTask {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        if (Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) == 4) {
            System.out.println(new Date());
        }
    }
}
```

and schedule it to run at the top of every hour. Task will decide which hour is 4 am in the current Locale